# Java Generics: Build Parameterized Classes for every inner class

Tags: java, generics

Say I have an interface:

```
public interface Authentication<T> {
   public void authenticate(T token);
}
```

I have a class called `AuthenticationMethods` that has several inner classes.

what I want to do is write a utility where I can get all the inner classes, and generate a class that implements the `Authentication<T>` interface with the Type `T` of the inner class, like so:

```
for (Class clazz : AuthenticationMethods.class.getDeclaredClasses()){
   createAuthenticationImplClass(clazz);
}

private <T> Authentication<T> createAuthenticationImplClass(Class clazz){
  return new Authentication<clazz>() {
     @Override
     public void authenticate(clazz token) throws Exception {
        //do something with the token
     }
   };
}
```

Obviously just using `clazz` in place of `T` does not work.

How can i get the type from the clazz in to the parameterized implementation of the Authentication interface?

Comment: why do you need to pass the class into the method?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this.

```
private <T extends Class<?>> Authentication<T> createAuthenticationImplClass(T clazz){
  return new Authentication<T>() {
     @Override
     public void authenticate(T token) throws Exception {
        //do something with the token
     }
   };
}
```

Example

`Authentication<Class<String>> =  createAuthenticationImplClass(String.class);`

or this

```
private <T> Authentication<T> createAuthenticationImplClass(Class<T> clazz){
  return new Authentication<T>() {
     @Override
     public void authenticate(T token) throws Exception {
        //do something with the token
     }
   };
}
```

Example:

`Authentication<String> =  createAuthenticationImplClass(String.class);`

The difference is that in first example your `authenticate` method will have in parameter the Class type. In the second the parameter will be type that class represent.

Comment: I think you mean `<T> Authentication<T> createAuthenticationImplClass(Class<T> clazz)`.

Comment: No. Because then we will pass to `Authentication` the instance of class `T`. OP expect there the class... or not... hmm

Comment: Nope, I'm pretty sure.  You want to pass in a `Class<T>` and get back an `Authentication<T>`, not an `Authentication<Class<T>>`.

Comment: I really must disappoint you again. Thanks for sharing the thought regarding potential mistake, that was caused by vague OP description but my first answer was about `Authentication<Class<T>>` if you believe or not. ;-).

Comment: Yep.  My reading of the OP's question is that the OP wants an `Authentication<T>`, but if you read the question differently, that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to authenticate tokens of the `clazz` class. Then you need to parametrize your factory method parameter with generic Class type:

```
private <T> Authentication<T> createAuthenticationImplClass(Class<T> clazz){
    return new Authentication<T>() {
        @Override
        public void authenticate(T token) throws Exception {
            //do something with the token
        }
    };
}
```

Of course at the moment you do **for** loop for declared classes you lose generic types, so the only way to pass type-safe `Class` instance is explicit class name:

```
Authentication<TokenType> authForTokenType = createAuthenticationImplClass(TokenType.class);
```

Comment: well, I see the problem, but he can substitute loop with explicit calls like `createAuthenticationImplClass(TokenType1.class);` preserving type safety, but loosing extensibility. Ok, I am speaking to myself. Someone has just deleted comment

Comment: in this case, why do you need to pass `clazz` in at all (it's not used)?

Comment: class is not, but generic parameter is

Comment: yeah, but that generic parameter is determined (either explicitly or implicitly) by the caller. What I am saying is that if you remove it, it will still work (caller might need to specify parameter explicitly). That is, of course, assuming the OP doesn't need to use the class at all in the method (he didn't say, but I actually think he needs it, because otherwise it would make this method not be able to do much)

Comment: ok, i see what you mean and agree. this is leftover from original question, can be simplified to `Authentication<TokenType> authForTokenType = createAuthenticationImplClass();`